# Count number of Ints in Scala list using a fold

Tags: scala, fold

Say I have the following list of type Any:

```
val list = List("foo", 1, "bar", 2)
```

I would now like to write a function that counts only the number of Ints in a list using a fold. In the case of the list above, the result should be "2".

I know counting the number of all elements using fold would look something like this:

```
def count(list: List[Any]): Int =
  list.foldLeft(0)((sum,_) => sum + 1)
```

How can I tweak this to only count occurrences of Int?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another version:

```
list.count(_.isInstanceOf[Int])
```

And, if you insist on the `foldLeft` version, here is one:

```
def count(list: List[Any]): Int =
  list.foldLeft(0)((sum, x) => x match {
    case _: Int => sum + 1
    case _ => sum
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering `list` by `Int` and taking the `size` gives you what you want and is fairly straightforward.

```
scala> list.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).size
res0: Int = 2
```

Comment: Thanks and this is very straightforward, but I'm trying to better understand how this would work (or see if it's even possible) by specifically using a fold.

Comment: You can combine the two answers above:

list.filter(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).foldLeft(0)((sum,_) => sum + 1)